# Using Espresso, how can I detect an item of a listView within another listView

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a listView containing another listView containing images

In need to click on the first image

I wrote this statement:

```
onData(withRegistrationNo(registrationNo))
.inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.parent_listview), isDisplayed()))
.onChildView(withId(R.id.imageView))
.inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.child_listview),isDisplayed()))
.atPosition(0).perform(longClick());
```

**But this error appears:**
*Error performing 'load adapter data' on view '(with id: com.package.app:id/child_listview and is displayed on the screen to the user)'*

**What's wrong??**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.child_listview), isDisplayed(),
        isDescendantOfA(allOf(withId(R.id.parent_listview), isDisplayed()))))
    .atPosition(0).perform(longClick());
```

Comment: Great Solution @jeprubio, But how can I get a specific item of parent list

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check the text :

onView(allOf(withId(R.id.yourInnerListViewId),isDescendantOfA(allOf(withId(R.id.yourOuterListViewId),withText("xyz"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))));

If you want to perform action :

```
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.yourInnerListViewId),isDescendantOfA(allOf(withId(R.id.yourOuterListViewId),withText("xyz"))).perform(click())));
```